# Is it possible to use the same table three times & to alias one attribute same number of times as the table?

Tags: sql

The values for the attribute P1 and P2 works but as soon I  join third time does not work anymore for P3.

```
 SELECT x.A1, x.A2, x.A2 as P1,y.A2 as P2,z.A2 as P3
  FROM Contact x
  LEFT JOIN Contact y ON y.ID =x.P2
  LEFT JOIN Contact z ON y.ID =z.P3 
 WHERE (x.LN = y.LN)   AND
   ((x.res ='pre-sale') AND  (y.res= pos-sale') AND(z.res='current-sale') ) AND
((x.P1 IS NOT NULL) AND (y.P2 IS NOT NULL) AND (z.P3 IS NOT NULL) ) 
ORDER by x.LN DESC
```

Comment: Can you post the result of that code, perhaps, before that you stated as **worked**, and after that you stated as **not worked**. and perhaps you expected result

Comment: Is the last join perhaps meant to be `LEFT JOIN Contact z ON z.ID =x.P3`? also you are doing a LEFT JOIN but then checking for not null it is better to do a INNER JOIN which only joins non null items

Comment: Does not work even I applied simple query as below

Comment: Yes, i do expect the results on P1, P2, P3 
Results for
       P1 should come when (x.res ='pre-sale')
       P2 when (y.res= 'pos-sale') and 
       P3 when (z.res='current-sale')

Comment: Question remains unclear after repeated requests, voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use column alias on JOIN and WHERE clause. Try this query:

```
SELECT x.A1, x.A2, x.A2 as P1,y.A2 as P2,z.A2 as P3
  FROM Contact x
  LEFT JOIN Contact y ON y.ID =x.A2
  LEFT JOIN Contact z ON y.ID =z.A2 
 WHERE (x.LN = y.LN)   AND
   ((x.res ='pre-sale') AND  (y.res= 'pos-sale') AND(z.res='current-sale') ) AND
((x.A2 IS NOT NULL) AND (y.A2 IS NOT NULL) AND (z.A2 IS NOT NULL) ) 
ORDER by x.LN DESC
```

Comment: SELECT x.A1, x.A2, x.A2 as P1,y.A2 as P2,z.A2 as P3
FROM Contact x, Contact y, Contact z

Comment: WHERE (x.LN = y.LN)   AND
   ((x.res ='pre-sale') AND  (y.res= 'pos-sale') AND(z.res='current-sale') ) AND
((x.A2 IS NOT NULL) AND (y.A2 IS NOT NULL) AND (z.A2 IS NOT NULL) ) 
ORDER by x.LN DESC

Comment: still does not work for P3.  

SELECT x.A1, x.A2,  x.A2as P1,y.x.A2 as P2,x.A2 as P3 
FROM Contact x, Contact y,Contact z
 WHERE ( ( x.ObjectID = y.ObjectID  AND  y.ObjectID =ObjectID) AND   (x.LN = y.LN)  ) AND
       ((x.res ='pre-sale') AND  (y.res= pos-salet') AND(z.res='current-sale') ) AND
     ((x.P1 IS NOT NULL) AND (y.P2 IS NOT NULL) AND (z.P3 IS NOT NULL) ) 
ORDER by x.LN DESC

Answer (score 0):

Use the fundamental columns, not aliases, to describe your joins. Also it's more readable to put the "joined table" first and equate that to the "base-most table".

As I correct that you want to join Z & Y as "independent relationships" from X.. which is the most common case? The alternative is a two-stage relationship X->Y and Y->Z, but **since you don't say what you're doing** and **your column-names are meaningless**, nobody could ever tell.

Here's a possible example, for the X -> (Z, Y independently) structure.

```
SELECT x.A1, x.A2, x.A2 as P1, y.A2 as P2, z.A2 as P3
FROM Contact x
JOIN Contact y ON y.ID=x.P2 and y.LN=x.LN
JOIN Contact z ON z.ID=x.P3 and z.LN=x.LN        -- joining Z from X, not from Y;  also guessing a condition on LN like for X->Y
WHERE ((x.res ='pre-sale') AND (y.res='pos-sale') AND(z.res='current-sale')) 
ORDER by x.LN DESC
```

As I said, your question has posed an erroneous query with at least two problems and redundancies in it. It's kinda impossible to tell what is the correct query, since you haven't said your intention.

Please supply full & appropriate detail, and next time make sure to include this in your question.

Comment: single table CONTACT with several attributes A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7 
I want alias column A2 as follows A2 as P1, A2 as P2, A2 as P3
Expect the results for P1, P2, P3 
For:       P1 when (x.A4 ='pre-sale') - must return the values for P1 (22,44,..)
              P2 when (y.A4= 'pos-sale') - must return the values for P2 (31,61, ..)
              P3 when (z.A4='current-sale') - must return the values for P3(2,11, ..)

Comment: Example CONTACT table

A1  A2        A3     A4                 A5     A6     A7 
1    22       a     pre-sale            kk     8      4
2    31       b     pos-sale            yy     6      3
3    2        c     current-sale        hh     2      3
4    44       a     pre-sale            kk     8      4
5    61       b     pos-sale            yy     6      3
6   11        c    current-sale         hh     2      3

Comment: To be really clear -- is Z relatable directly from X, or is Z only relatable directly from Y? Really I'm asking a question about _the fundamental logical structure of your relationships_. Software design & problem-solving is based on _meaning_, I wasn't really asking for meaningless sample data. It looks like it's about `pre-sale`, `current sale` and (possibly?) `post-sale` roles of the CONTACT table. A proper answer from you would be specific, saying that Z is a (whatever role) and it is joined from X or Y (and what roles they play).